# Data Chart to show times of day in Excel

Tags: excel, datetime, charts

I have a data set where by i am required to show the sum of calls for a date and their call times also.

Here is an example of my data set for a few days for one extension

6/24/11 7:43:38 AM 
6/24/11 8:10:23 AM 
6/24/11 8:16:54 AM 
6/24/11 8:20:45 AM 
6/24/11 4:47:06 PM 
6/25/11 12:38:43 PM 
6/25/11 5:38:10 PM
6/26/11 7:32:53 AM 
6/27/11 5:40:32 PM 
6/28/11 3:46:05 PM 
6/29/11 7:09:21 PM 
6/30/11 5:59:54 AM 
6/30/11 1:21:28 PM 
6/30/11 5:59:00 PM

Is it possible to put this into a chart whereby we can see a sum of calls for a given date? If that makes sense.

Thanks,c

-=

I found the following post at [Excel Timesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200667/excel-timesheet)

this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to have a number of helper columns:

Example:
Column A through C contain the raw data for Extension 1-3
Column D through E contain the 'truncated' version of the time stamp into days
Column H through K would contain the frequency of calls for a given day and extension

Put the formula in E in order to get the truncated day, and expand it over the columns E-G

```
=DATE(YEAR(A3),MONTH(A3),DAY(A3))
```

Put the starting day of interest in Cell I2.  For Cell I3 enter the formula

```
=I3+1
```

so you will have automatically incrementing days in that column, this is your 'bin' for the histogram you're about to make.

Count the number of times the value in E is found for a day in your bin
In J ( column counting calls per day for extension 1 ) enter the formula:

```
=COUNTIF(E$3:E$16,$I3)
```

drag this formula out.

Now you should have the data for your histogram/plot in columns I through L.

[image: example screenshot]

Comment: Hi Tom. Great reply. Im trying to implement it now. however, VALUE! is showing do i need to trim AM PM?

Comment: the am/pm should be handled automatically by Excel itself.  No need to trim that.  When you paste or import the data in excel it should be recognized as a date/time format.  If not, you just need to set the cell-format manually.  Should not be necessary though.

o, depending on your international settings you may have to use ; in stead of , in your formulas though.  Which formula is giving grief?

Comment: ok cool.i changed the cell format. but the formula that isnt working is the DATE formla. im just getting the date and time of A3 in E3 it isn't making the time 00:00 as in your example.

Comment: actually my bad. it is still showing as VALUE! this is the exact value of A3 = 6/24/11 7:43:38

Comment: just a hunch... try
`=DAY(TRIM(A3))` 
If there are spaces left, these formulas tend to fail

Comment: i think its a regional thing.

Comment: what happens if you enter `=A3+1` ?  That should increment by 1 day.  If that is no good, the next thing to try is `=Trim(A3)+1` to check for leading/trailing spaces.  Good way to check is to manually enter a date and see what your regional settings prefer...

Comment: I don't have a way of testing that I'm afraid.  Sorry to leave you hanging there :(.
You could always try to put columns E and up in text format using
`=TEXT(A3,"dd-mm-yy")` but not sure how that would work out with the regional things.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following post at Excel Timesheet

this fixed my problem.

[Excel Timesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200667/excel-timesheet)